# Sales planing overview values of different objects

Tags: visualforce, reporting

I need for our sales colleagues to a list of responsible accounts for sales planning. I can do that quickly with a report, but I need this list enriched with additional information. For example sales last year (sales object), sales current year (sales object), current planning (object opportunity).

Can I build a report that displays the cumulative values ​​of these objects?
If not, how can I solve this via a visualforce site?

Account Sales Last Year Sales Current Year  Opportunity Amount

ABC 5.000 20.000    50.000

DEF 10.000  5.000   25.000

GHI 0   1.500   0

Answer (score 1):

If your objects are not connected then getting them into one report might be tough. I have a object similar to sales that reports revenue. It has lookups to both Account and Opportunity so you can report on everything at the lower level.

I suggest thinking about your report not from Account down to the objects but from the Sales object up to Account.

If you create a custom report type starting with Sales then pull in fields via lookup, you could get Opportunity and even Accounts too as Opportunities are child records of Account.

Comment: My relationship shows as follows: Account (Standard) -> Contract1 (Custom) -> Contract2 (Custom) -> Sales (Custom), Opportunity (Standard) has no relation to Sales, so I can't create a report with Sales and Opps, or?

Comment: So you can't then unless Contact1 or Contract2 is related to Opportunity.

Comment: Ok, what can I do? Can I create a report with visualforce?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure.